# preventDefault to not affect its children

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, unbind

I have the following to prevent a click event and slideToggle a sub navigation, the problem is it prevents the child links (in it's sub navigation)from working. How do I either target the parent without effecting the children or unbind the preventDefault?

```
 $('#sidr-main .submenu-button a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "[>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)" child selector, to select only first-level descendants

Your selector should be like this:

```
$('#sidr-main .submenu-button > a')
```